# Is there any way to know whether any Analytics are done for a site or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, analytics

I am developing a site in rails which requires information whether any analytics like google analytics or any other analytics tool are done for the entered website's URL.For example if i enter:http://facebook.com  and click on checkAnalytics button, then it results in either Yes or No..which would be yes in this case.
Please let me know if any one has a solution to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are online services that scrape this information.

[https://www.ghostery.com](http://www.ghostery.com) makes a browser extension that looks for 3rd party scripts like ad networks and analytics.

For our internal CRM we just request the website's main page, and check to look for strings in the HTML like 'google-analytics'.

You can use the [OpenURI ruby library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) to get the content of the website's page.

Hope this helps!